# Does tag record state of branch or the entire repository?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I have two branches "master" and "develop". I have been tagging the master branch with version numbers (i.e. "v1.2.3") and have started to tag BETA releases in a similar fashion ("v2.3.4-beta-1") whilst working on the develop branch.

Does the tag represent the state on the "develop" branch, or is it marking the state of the entire repository?

If so, is there a way to list which tags are associated with which branches so that I can verify whether I have been tagging properly up until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag is basically just a label for a specific commit—it points to a given commit—so it basically marks the state of the repo at that specific commit.